# Add Image/Media to Esri Field Maps Form

Tags: arcgis-field-maps

I setup a custom pop-up on a feature layer in the ArcGIS Online Map Viewer. I added a Media (image) content to the Pop-Up. In Map Viewer, I can select a point feature in the feature layer and the image appears in the Pop-Up. All good here!

I'd like the same Media content (image) to display in my Field Maps Form, but when I open Forms and select "Convert pop-up" the media content doesn't transfer over. Only the Fields do. I don't see Media or Image as an Element option in the Form Builder either.

Can anyone confirm if it's possible to add an image to your Field Maps Form?

[image]